# How do I do dynamic headers columns in CDE Pentaho?

Tags: components, pentaho

I have a table component and I need from the second column to have two subcolumns, but the first one the data comes from the database respectively with the subcolumn data.

Similar to this link https://forums.pentaho.com/threads/140282-Table-Component-SubColumns/, the titles' TIM ',' Vodafone 'and' Wide 'are fixed, but the titles' Latenza Media' and 'Through. Download Media 'comes dynamically from the database.

How to make?

Answer (score 0):

On postFetch, pass a data argument and parse data.metadata to fetch the the column headers you need.

Use that to modify this.colHeaders* property of the table component.

- speaking from memory, it may be a different property, please use your browser’s debugger and check proper spelling.